# Conversion problems from mappoint to screenpoint using ArcGis Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cartography

I am getting a very strange problem when converting from mappoint to screenpoint.

I am using the following code:

```
var sp = esri.geometry.ScreenPoint(512, 151);
    mp = map.toMap(screenPoint);
```

After converting from screenpoint(512, 151) to mappoint, I get the following map coordinates:

```
338638.7275175141, 4404774.250335829
```

Now when I perform the reverse conversion (i.e., from the same point above which is mappoint(338638.7275175141, 4404774.250335829) to screenPoint), I get a very different screenpoint (i.e. 31563417740, -72455974). I think I should get the same screenpoint(512, 151) coordinate. For this reverse conversion I am using the following code:

```
mp1 = new esri.geometry.Point(338638.7275175141, 4404774.250335829);
sp1 = map.toScreen(mp1);
```

With it, I get a very different screenpoint as I showed before and no the value (512,151).

Any help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

you're using at the beginning:

```
var sp = esri.geometry.ScreenPoint(512, 151);
    mp = map.toMap(screenPoint);
```

and then:

```
mp1 = new esri.geometry.Point(338638.7275175141, 4404774.250335829);
sp1 = map.toScreen(mp1);
```

I'm wondering if the right syntax is this:

```
var sp = esri.geometry.ScreenPoint(512, 151);
var mp = map.toMap(sp);

var mp1 = new esri.geometry.Point(338638.7275175141, 4404774.250335829);
var sp1 = map.toScreen(mp1);
```